# R - how to use a function on a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, function

I have a little problem with my code. I hope you can help me :)

I used a function apply to create a list of 20 data frames (data about stock index returns, grouped by year and index - about three companies and the stock, for 5 years). And now I want to use function with two arguments (it calculates proportion of covariance of the returns for selected company and the stock to variance (for every year) - this is why I'm trying to group the data. How to do it... automatically, without manual typing code for every year and company?

I don't have any idea if I should use *for* loop or there is any other way...?
And the other thing is in which way can I delete uneccesary columns from list of data frames?

I'll be thankful for your help.
And sorry for my English :D

Comment: The ‘mapply’ function will accept data in multiple columns to be successively processed my a function.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score -1):

You may consider `purrr::map_dfr()`. The first argument will be your list of data frames, and the second the action to do with that data frame. The final result will be a single data frame uniting the result of all of the above. Your code will likely look something like this:

`purrr::map_dfr(list_of_dataframes, function(x) {...})`

Within the bracketes, instead of ... insert your logic. In that context, x will be the same as `list_of_dataframes[[1]]`, and then `list_of_dataframes[[2]]`, etc.

You may want to consult the documentation of the package `purrr` for further details.